# I'm not sure why my code doesn't update the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

![picture of output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLNbx.jpg

> the code is supposed to allow the user to select from a list of motorhomes to update the details, providing a form that send the updated information to the database.

> this first part is where you can select which motorhome you would like to edit the details of.

```
//List to choose motorhome
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <nav>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h2>Please choose a motorhome to update</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="120px">Manufacturer</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Year Of Manufacture</th>
          <th>Engine</th>
          <th>Berths</th>
          <th>Milage</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Layout</th>
          <th>Ownership</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <?php
          try {
              require_once("functions.php");
              $dbConn = getConnection();

              $sqlQuery = "SELECT motorHomeID, manufacturer, model, yearOfManufacture, engine, berths, mileage, price, layout, ownership, description
                         FROM tvmh_motorhomes";

              $queryResult = $dbConn->query($sqlQuery);

              while($rowObj = $queryResult->fetchObject()){
                echo "
                <tr>
                  <td width='120px'><a href='tvmh_editForm.php?motorHomeID={$rowObj->motorHomeID}'>{$rowObj->manufacturer}</td>
                  <td width='120px'>{$rowObj->model}</td>
                  <td width='120px'>{$rowObj->yearOfManufacture}</td>
                  <td width='120px'>{$rowObj->engine}</td>
                  <td width='120px'>{$rowObj->berths}</td>
                  <td width='120px'>{$rowObj->mileage}</td>
                  <td width='120px'>{$rowObj->price}</td>
                  <td width='120px'>{$rowObj->layout}</td>
                  <td width='120px'>{$rowObj->ownership}</td>
                  <td width='120px'>{$rowObj->description}</td>
                </tr>
                ";

              }
          }
          catch (Exception $e){
              echo "<p>Query failed: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n";
          }
           ?>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

> this part is where the user is provided with a form to edit the details of the selected motorhome.

```
//Form to edit motor home details
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Edit Motorhome</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  $motorHomeID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'motorHomeID') ? $_GET['motorHomeID'] : null;

  if(empty($motorHomeID)){
    echo "<p>Please <a href='tvmh_choose.php'>choose</a> a motorhome.</p>\n";
  }
  else{
    try{
      require_once("functions.php");
      $dbConn = getConnection();

      $sqlQuery = "SELECT motorHomeID, manufacturer, model, yearOfManufacture, engine, berths, mileage, price, layout, ownership, description
                 FROM tvmh_motorhomes
                 WHERE motorHomeID = $motorHomeID";

      $queryResult = $dbConn->query($sqlQuery);

      $rowObj = $queryResult->fetchObject();

           echo "
            <h1>Update '{$rowObj->manufacturer} {$rowObj->model}'</h1>
            <form id='UpdateMotorhome' action='tvmh_edit.php' method='get'>
                <p>Motorhome ID <input type='text' name='motorHomeID' value='$motorHomeID' readonly /></p>
                <p>Manufacture <input type='text' name=',manufacturer' size='50' value='{$rowObj->manufacturer}' /></p>
                <p>Model <input type='text' name=',model' size='50' value='{$rowObj->model}' /></p>
                <p>Year Of Manufacture <input type='text' name=',yearOfManufacture' size='50' value='{$rowObj->yearOfManufacture}' /></p>
                <p>Engine <input type='text' name=',engine' size='50' value='{$rowObj->engine}' /></p>
                <p>Berths <input type='text' name=',berths' size='50' value='{$rowObj->berths}' /></p>
                <p>Mileage <input type='text' name=',mileage' size='50' value='{$rowObj->mileage}' /></p>
                <p>Price <input type='text' name=',price' size='50' value='{$rowObj->price}' /></p>
                <p>Layout <input type='text' name=',layout' size='50' value='{$rowObj->layout}' /></p>
                <p>Ownership <input type='text' name=',ownership' size='50' value='{$rowObj->ownership}' /></p>
                Description <br />
                <textarea name='description'>{$rowObj->description}</textarea>
                <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='UpdateMotorhome'></p>
              </form>
                ";
        }
    catch (Exception $e){
        echo "<p>Motohome was not found: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n";
    }
  }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

> this part is the script that takes the data from the form and updates it to the database.

```
//Script to update 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tvmh Edit Motorhome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Edit Motorhome</h1>


<?php
$motorHomeID = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'motorHomeID') ? $_GET['motorHomeID'] : null;
$manufacturer = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'manufacturer') ? $_GET['manufacturer'] : null;
$model = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'model') ? $_GET['model'] : null;
$yearOfManufacture = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'yearOfManufacture') ? $_GET['yearOfManufacture'] : null;
$engine = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'engine') ? $_GET['engine'] : null;
$berths = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'berths') ? $_GET['berths'] : null;
$mileage = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'mileage') ? $_GET['mileage'] : null;
$price = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'price') ? $_GET['price'] : null;
$layout = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'layout') ? $_GET['layout'] : null;
$ownership = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'ownership') ? $_GET['ownership'] : null;
$description = filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'description') ? $_GET['description'] : null;

$errors = false;

if (empty($motorHomeID)) {
    echo "<p>You need to have selected an ID.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($manufacturer)) {
    echo "<p>You need to have selected a manufacturer.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($model)) {
    echo "<p>You need to choose a model.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($yearOfManufacture)) {
    echo "<p>You need to choose a Year Of Manufacture.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($engine)) {
    echo "<p>You need to have selected an engine.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($berths)) {
    echo "<p>You need to have selected a number of berths.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($mileage)) {
    echo "<p>You need to choose a mileage.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($price)) {
    echo "<p>You need to choose a price.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($layout)) {
    echo "<p>You need to choose a layout.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($ownership)) {
    echo "<p>You need to choose a ownership.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if (empty($description)) {
    echo "<p>You need to add a description.</p>\n";
    $errors = true;
}
if ($errors === true) {
    echo "<p>Please try <a href='tvmh_choose.php'>again</a>.</p>\n";
}
  else {
    try {
        require_once("functions.php");
        $dbConn = getConnection();

        $manufacturer = $dbConn->quote($manufacturer);
        $model = $dbConn->quote($model);
        $yearOfManufacture = $dbConn->quote($yearOfManufacture);
        $engine = $dbConn->quote($engine);
        $berths = $dbConn->quote($berths);
        $mileage = $dbConn->quote($mileage);
        $price = $dbConn->quote($price);
        $layout = $dbConn->quote($layout);
        $ownership = $dbConn->quote($ownership);
        $description = $dbConn->quote($description);

        $updateSQL = "UPDATE tvmh_motorhomes
                      SET manufacturer = $manufacturer, model = $model, yearOfManufacture = $yearOfManufacture, engine = $engine, berths = $berths, mileage = $mileage, price = $price, layout = $layout, ownership = $ownership, description = $description
                      WHERE motorHomeID = $motorHomeID";

        $dbConn->exec($updateSQL);
        echo "<p>Motorhome Updated</p>\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<p>Motorhome not Updated!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>\n";
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline variables should be with apostrophes. Eg: `$updateSQL = "UPDATE myDb SET key1='$value1', key2='$value2'"`

Or you could concatenate them:

`$updateSQL = "UPDATE myDb SET key1=".$value1.", key2=".$value2."`

Comment: Hi this didn't work, i'll try and edit my original question to show you the output when i changed the code to what you said